# How can I add click event to kendoGridCellTemplate

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to figure out how can I add a click event handler to kendo grid cell.
Here is my code :

```
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
          <div class="w-100 timeline-cell-container">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of getTimelineField(parentColumn.field, dataItem, true); let i=index">
              <div class="timeline-cell position-absolute" [ngStyle]="getTimelineCellStyle(item)">
                {{ item.value }}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
</ng-template>
```

I know I can add the onclick event to the inside div, but is there a way to attach it to the cell itself?
I've seen https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/CellClickEvent/ but didn't understand how to use it or if this is the right way to use it?
this is how I fill the cell information :

```
const buildObj = {
          value: [jobObject.job],
          type: 'cell',
          startFrom: this.calcTimelineJobStart(startDate, index, width),
          width,
          color: this.colorCode(jobObject.job),
          class:'hint'
        };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to wrap your `<ng-template>` tag with a `<kendo-grid>` tag, then you can use the cell click event emitter `(cellClick)="cellClickHandler($event)`

```
<kendo-grid #grid (cellClick)="cellClickHandler($event)">
<ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
          <div class="w-100 timeline-cell-container">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of getTimelineField(parentColumn.field, dataItem, true); let i=index">
              <div class="timeline-cell position-absolute" [ngStyle]="getTimelineCellStyle(item)">
                {{ item.value }}
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
</ng-template>
<kendo-grid/>
```

Then you implement `cellClickHandler` in your typescript file:

```
public cellClickHandler({ sender, rowIndex, columnIndex, dataItem, isEdited }) {
  // your code here
  console.log(rowIndex, columnIndex)
}
```

Take a look at this documentation for more: [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/#toc-basic-concepts)

Comment: thanks a lot ! 
I was looking for an example on how to use the event!